# No SCNGeometry Available in SCNReferenceNode?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I'm downloading a collada file from a web server and would like to map textures programmatically, but there's SCNGeometry is nil. Can anyone give a suggestion? Below is sample code.

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/dae.dae")!
    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

    Alamofire.download(
        url,
        method: .get,
        parameters: nil,
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: nil,
        to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            print(progress)
        }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
            let path = DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL
            let node = SCNReferenceNode(url: path!)
            node?.load()
            print(node)
            print(node?.geometry)
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node!)
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. SCNReferenceNode contains an array of nodes, so in order to assign a texture, you need to index into it.

```
node?.childNodes.first?.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "example.png")
```